# How do I store passwords to my mailfunciton in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, security, .net-core

I made a website out of .NET Framework recently and I could put my passwords in a web.config file. But now I have updated myself and is currently using .NET Core 3.1. Where can I store my passwords and/or do I need to encrypt them? Thanks beforehand!

Best regards Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you are referring to passwords relating to application configuration you can refer to the below options.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1